# How to search for an element in a golang slice

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a slice of structs.

```
type Config struct {
    Key string
    Value string
}

// I form a slice of the above struct
var myconfig []Config 

// unmarshal a response body into the above slice
if err := json.Unmarshal(respbody, &myconfig); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(config)
```

Here is the output of this:

```
[{key1 test} {web/key1 test2}]
```

How can I search this array to get the element where `key="key1"`?

Comment: As your Config struct looks like a simple map I want to point out that you can decode any JSON data to a `map[string]interface{}`. If you're interested, checkout [this official blog post](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Starting with Go 1.21, there's the [`slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) package in the standard lib with a generic search function named [`slices.IndexFunc()`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#IndexFunc):

> ```
> func IndexFunc[S ~[]E, E any](s S, f func(E) bool) int
> ```
>
> IndexFunc returns the first index i satisfying f(s[i]), or -1 if none do.

Using that:

```
idx := slices.IndexFunc(myconfig, func(c Config) bool { return c.Key == "key1" })
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BOr0IVsKQvn).

For older versions read on.

Before Go 1.21, it was part of an external repository: [`golang.org/x/exp/slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices) package which contains a generic "find" function named [`slices.IndexFunc()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#IndexFunc):

Prior to Go 1.18 and for a faster alternative, read on:

With a simple `for` loop:

```
for _, v := range myconfig {
    if v.Key == "key1" {
        // Found!
    }
}
```

Note that since element type of the slice is a `struct` (not a pointer), this may be inefficient if the struct type is "big" as the loop will copy each visited element into the loop variable.

It would be faster to use a `range` loop just on the index, this avoids copying the elements:

```
for i := range myconfig {
    if myconfig[i].Key == "key1" {
        // Found!
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

It depends on your case whether multiple configs may exist with the same `key`, but if not, you should `break` out of the loop if a match is found (to avoid searching for others).

```
for i := range myconfig {
    if myconfig[i].Key == "key1" {
        // Found!
        break
    }
}
```

Also if this is a frequent operation, you should consider building a `map` from it which you can simply index, e.g.

```
// Build a config map:
confMap := map[string]string{}
for _, v := range myconfig {
    confMap[v.Key] = v.Value
}

// And then to find values by key:
if v, ok := confMap["key1"]; ok {
    // Found
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am free to use pointers as well. Do you think using a pointer to struct    would be faster here? Can we have an array of pointers?

Comment: @love2code Yes, you may use slice of pointers too, or if you loop over the indices (as in my 2nd example), then values will not be copied. Up to you.

Comment: ok I created `var myconfig []*Config` and used your 1st approach. I hope this is the best option performance wise

Comment: @love2code Best option performance wise is to build a map from it which you can index. See edited answer.

Comment: Note that golang.org/x/exp/slices is experimental. I wouldn't recommend using it at this stage.

Comment: Is there a go to consensus of which look up is "faster" and "efficient"? Given the examples replicated by @icza?

Comment: Creating a map is not more efficient (memory-wise) since it requires making a new map, which uses memory. It is also not always faster. For infrequent checks in a small slice, it will take longer to make the new map than to simply traverse the slice to check. If # of checks is m, then naive loop through the slice: O(m*n) vs make map then check: O(n) to make map + O(m) to check if an item is in the map. Most of the time, for a reasonable size slice and a reasonable number of checks, then making a map makes sense. But not always!

Comment: @TomAnderson Obviously the map solution is to be used if the slice doesn't change (or not often), and you build the map once, and use it for multiple checks. If you only need to check once, obviously building a map is an unnecessary overhead as that requires iterating over all element once, while searching for an element might not even require iterating over the whole slice (not to mention building a map requires hashing and other calculations).

Answer (score 35):

You can use `sort.Slice()` plus `sort.Search()`

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    crowd := []Person{{"Zoey"}, {"Anna"}, {"Benni"}, {"Chris"}}

    sort.Slice(crowd, func(i, j int) bool {
        return crowd[i].Name <= crowd[j].Name
    })

    needle := "Benni"
    idx := sort.Search(len(crowd), func(i int) bool {
        return string(crowd[i].Name) >= needle
    })

    if idx < len(crowd) && crowd[idx].Name == needle {
        fmt.Println("Found:", idx, crowd[idx])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Found noting: ", idx)
    }
}
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/47OPrjKb0g_c

Comment: You should check whether returned index out of range first, before compare.

Answer (score 11):

You can save the struct into a map by matching the struct `Key` and `Value` components to their fictive key and value parts on the map:

```
mapConfig := map[string]string{}
for _, v := range myconfig {
   mapConfig[v.Key] = v.Value
}
```

Then using the golang *comma ok* idiom you can test for the key presence:

```
if v, ok := mapConfig["key1"]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("%s exists", v)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no library function for that. You have to code by your own.

```
for _, value := range myconfig {
    if value.Key == "key1" {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Working code: https://play.golang.org/p/IJIhYWROP_

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Config struct {
        Key   string
        Value string
    }

    var respbody = []byte(`[
        {"Key":"Key1", "Value":"Value1"},
        {"Key":"Key2", "Value":"Value2"}
    ]`)

    var myconfig []Config

    err := json.Unmarshal(respbody, &myconfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", myconfig)

    for _, v := range myconfig {
        if v.Key == "Key1" {
            fmt.Println("Value: ", v.Value)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is coming from Java or C# like me this is what I ended up doing:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

```
// create slice of people
var people []Person = []Person{
    {"Tono", 33},
    {"Regina", 25},
    {"Bob", 40},
}

// find person where its Name equals to Bob <------------------
bob := FirstOrDefault(people, func(p *Person) bool { return p.Name == "Bob" })

if bob != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Found bob: %v \n", *bob)
} else {
    fmt.Println("could not find bob")
}

peopleOlderThan30 := Where(people, func(p *Person) bool { return p.Age > 30 })

fmt.Println("People older than 30 are:")
for _, element := range peopleOlderThan30 {
    fmt.Println(*element)
}
```

I was able to run that code with the help of these functions:

```
func FirstOrDefault[T any](slice []T, filter func(*T) bool) (element *T) {

    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        if filter(&slice[i]) {
            return &slice[i]
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func Where[T any](slice []T, filter func(*T) bool) []*T {

    var ret []*T = make([]*T, 0)

    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        if filter(&slice[i]) {
            ret = append(ret, &slice[i])
        }
    }

    return ret
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As other guyspeople commented before, you can write your own procedure with an anonymous function to solve this issue.

I used two ways to solve it:

```
func Find(slice interface{}, f func(value interface{}) bool) int {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    if s.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for index := 0; index < s.Len(); index++ {
            if f(s.Index(index).Interface()) {
                return index
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Uses example:

```
type UserInfo struct {
    UserId          int
}

func main() {
    var (
        destinationList []UserInfo
        userId      int = 123
    )
    
    destinationList = append(destinationList, UserInfo { 
        UserId          : 23,
    }) 
    destinationList = append(destinationList, UserInfo { 
        UserId          : 12,
    }) 
    
    idx := Find(destinationList, func(value interface{}) bool {
        return value.(UserInfo).UserId == userId
    })
    
    if idx < 0 {
        fmt.Println("not found")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(idx)    
    }
}
```

Second method with less computational cost:

```
func Search(length int, f func(index int) bool) int {
    for index := 0; index < length; index++ {
        if f(index) {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Uses example:

```
type UserInfo struct {
    UserId          int
}

func main() {
    var (
        destinationList []UserInfo
        userId      int = 123
    )
    
    destinationList = append(destinationList, UserInfo { 
        UserId          : 23,
    }) 
    destinationList = append(destinationList, UserInfo { 
        UserId          : 123,
    }) 
    
    idx := Search(len(destinationList), func(index int) bool {
        return destinationList[index].UserId == userId
    })
    
    if  idx < 0 {
        fmt.Println("not found")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(idx)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function based on @Tarion's answer.

```
func findProgram (programs []Program, id uint) (Program, error) {
    sort.Slice(programs, func(i, j int) bool {
        return programs[i].ID <= programs[j].ID
    })

    idx := sort.Search(len(programs), func(i int) bool {
        return programs[i].ID >= id
    })

    if idx < len(programs) && programs[idx].ID == id {
        return programs[idx], nil
    } else {
        return Program{}, fmt.Errorf("program not found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks for every element in the slice, including substrings.
Case insensitive.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func findSubstring(sliceStrings []string, substring string) []string {
    substring = strings.ToLower(substring)
    var matches []string
    for _, v := range sliceStrings {
        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(v), substring) {
            matches = append(matches, v)
        }
    }
    return matches
}

func main() {
    sliceStrings := []string{"Hello", "World", "world2", "golang"}
    substring := "oRl"
    matches := findSubstring(sliceStrings, substring)
    for _, value := range matches {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/m5UAgbvPbbR

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function like `Array.prototype.find()` in Javascript, create this function:

```
func array_find[T any](a []T, fn func(u *T) bool) *T {
    for k, v := range a {
        if fn(&v) {
            return &a[k]
        }
    }
    var empty T
    return &empty
}
```

And it is easy to use:

```
tom := array_find(users, func(u *User) bool {
        return u.name == "Tom"
    })
```

Just like `Array.prototype.find()`, you get the reference of that object. Means, if you change values of `tom`, the values of original `users` also change.